# always show the options for select tag even after hiding some

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Hi i have this code that will hide an option once its already selected by other select tags on the same page, the problem now is that when a lot of the options have been selected the height of the drop down decreases to the point where the other choices are not visible anymore. is there a way for the height of the drop down to stop decreasing?

Thank you.

Hiding function:

```
function updateOthers2(val) {
    $("option").show();
    $(".tblboxes").each(function (i) {
        var obj = $("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']");
        if ($(this).val() != "") obj.hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to supplement your question for clarity.

Comment: Why not simply disable it instead of hiding it?

Comment: @j08691 what would be the difference?

Comment: Disabling keeps it visible but unselectable (grayed out) and you won't have to worry about the changing height.

Comment: @j08691 all i have to do is obj.disable();?

Comment: No it's a property you set like this `.prop('disabled',true)`:http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3MHr4/

Comment: so i can have it like obj.prop('disabled', true)

Comment: i changed it to obj.attr('disabled', true); and got it to work, thanks.